# jq: pass string argument without quotes

Tags: jq

I would like to pass an argument without quotes (JQ arg has double quotes by default) since it should be used as a filter. For e.g.

```
propt='.properties'
final=($(jq -r -c --arg p $propt '$p' sample.json))
echo $final
```

sample.json

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Contains information",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "description": "Type"
        }
   }
}
```

So ultimately it prints out `.properties` instead of the expected `{"type":{"description":"Type"}}`
I use a bash shell for this purpose.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to distinguish between *literal* and *syntactic* quotes. Syntactic quotes aren't passed to `jq` at all, they're passed to bash. Thus, jq can't do anything to not need them, since it has no control over how bash parses the command before invoking it.

Comment: BTW, the Markdown here isn't GitHub-flavored: Triple backticks don't have any special meaning, and don't enable code formatting for multi-line blocks. Use the `{}` button with a block selected to indent each line by four spaces to enable syntax highlighting.

Comment: ...by the way, `final=( $(...) ); echo $final` is also buggy -- it string-splits and glob-expands `jq`'s output to generate a list of words, assigning that list to an array, but then only prints the first element of that array. `final=$(...); echo "$final"` would be less broken, as it explicitly uses a string rather than an array. Alternately, `mapfile -t final < <(jq ...); printf 'Item: %s\n' "${final[@]}"` is similarly less buggy, building an array with one entry per line of output from `jq`, and passing each piece in the array as a separate argument to `printf`.

Comment: (Ahh -- it actually took hobbs's answer to get me to understand what you meant by "without quotes" in the question. There **are** no literal quotes created; thinking of jq as if `--arg foo string` adds quotes around `string` is a serious misunderstanding of the execution model. If you've ever built a parser for a language that builds an AST, think of it that way -- the quotes are part of the syntax, they aren't part of the data; that's true at the jq level, not just the shell level).

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you're getting sidetracked by thinking you need to set up a variable in `jq`, instead of just letting the shell do an expansion:

```
% foo='.properties'
% jq -r -c  "$foo" sample.json
```

output:

```
{"type":{"description":"Type"}}
```

Note the double quotes on $foo to still allow the shell to expand the variable to .properties. That said you could unsafely use: `jq -r -c  $foo sample.json`

Comment: I answered on the assumption that there's some reason for the indirection/separation in the original... but if there's not, then this is a perfectly good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `--arg` in that way. The value of a `--arg` is a string, not a jq filter expression. If you do `--arg p .properties`, then `$p` will contain the string `".properties"`, it won't be evaluated as a program. Find a different way to do what you want, perhaps by defining a function.

For example, if you prefixed your program with `def p: .properties;` then you could use `.|p` in your program in the way that you're using `$p` now, and it would access the `.properties` of whatever value is in context.

Comment: I tried using custom function as you indicated above. But the problem I have is that .properties is dynamic, it may be a different path for a different context so a function can be defined but since it is dynamic it requires an argument to be passed as well.

Comment: @user915534 then I think you will need to ask a clearer question, sorry.

Comment: Sure, do i have to post a new question ? Ultimately what I am looking for is a way to pass a variable argument to JQ program and the argument will be used as a filter.

Comment: @user915534 a new question might be in order given the confusion that's gone on here, but you also have the option of editing the current one to clarify. I would suggest providing some background on *why* you're doing this, to help people provide a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since jq does not have an “eval” function, the appropriate way to specify a path programmatically in jq is using a JSON array in conjunction with jq’s `getpath` and `setpath` built-ins, as appropriate.

Thus in your case you could use the -—argjson command-line option to pass in the path of interest, e.g.

```
-—argson p '["properties"]'
```

and your jq program would use `getpath($p)`.

Needless to say, this approach works for arbitrarily nested paths.