# jq: pass variable argument to be used as filter

Tags: jq

How do I pass a *variable* argument to JQ program that will be used as a filter. Since by default --arg passes the argument as a a string wrapped with quotes the same cannot be used to apply a filter.

here is the JQ program that finds a particular path in the given json and adds a static key value to that path but doesn't work because of the quotes issue.

```
--argjson name '{ "pattern": "XYZ"}' 'def p: "." + (paths | select(.[-1] == "p-enum") | .[0:-1] | join(".")) ; .|p += $name' sample.json
```

here is the sample json

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "description": "Contains information.",
  "properties": {
    "type": {
      "description": "Type.",
      "type": "string",
      "p-enum": [
        {
          "value": "IND",
          "description": "Ind."
        },
        {
          "value": "PROP",
          "description": "Prop."
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You generally wouldn't/shouldn't pass in "programs" as arguments to your program. In this context, the filter is the program. For all the same reasons of why eval() and equivalents shouldn't be used and also simply, it's not supported here. Think of a different way to formulate your filters. If that's not an option, just run your variable filter as the filter itself...

Answer (score 1):

Based on how I interpreted how you were using jq in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52173556), it depends on how complicated your filter will be. Any argument that is to be interpreted by `jq` is not the way you should approach it. This is the equivalent of using `eval()` and is not only unsupported, but just not a good way to approach this.

If you're simply accessing a property of the input, you have a couple of ways using simple indexing or using `getpath/1` for nested paths.

```
# indexing
# { "properties": ... }
$ jq --arg p 'properties' '.[$p]' input.json
```

```
# using getpath
# { "foo": { "bar": ... } }
$ jq --argjson path '["foo","bar"]' 'getpath($path)' input.json
```

Comment: The property is derived. All I have is a specific key and a json file. My intention is to scan through the json file, get the path for that particular key and add a new static key:value as a sibling to that path. So the way I planned to do it is, get the path and pipe it as a filter with += "key:value". However when i try to do it, i get path expression invalid since JQ considers the filter with quotes and therefore doesn't work. I can paste all the code if needed.

Comment: Modified my question with more inputs, please check @hobbs

Comment: I tried using .[$arg] and it only works one level. Doesn't work for nested structure.